# ¿Cómo puedo acceder al historial (línea de tiempo) de una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, línea-de-tiempo

¿Existe alguna forma de ver un historial de eventos (ediciones sugeridas, comentarios, votos, etc..) de las preguntas ordenados por fecha? Es decir, ¿cómo se puede ver su línea de tiempo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No existe ningún enlace directo al historial de las preguntas, a pesar de que sí está implementado. Para poder verlo hay que editar una URL de forma manual de la siguiente manera:

1.- Debemos fijarnos en el id de la pregunta en la barra de tareas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Para acceder a la línea de tiempo, componemos la siguiente URL utilizando este id:

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/id/timeline
```

Por ejemplo, usando el id de la captura anterior, la URL sería la siguiente:

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/100237/timeline
```

Con esta URL ya accedemos a la [línea de tiempo de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/100237/timeline):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pulsando en `alternar formato`, podemos cambiar de *hace x minutos* al timestamp exacto de cada evento:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Truco para que sea mas sencillo acceder, por @fedorqui:

Pulsando el enlace `Editar` con el botón del medio del ratón,se abre en una nueva pestaña el formulario de edición. Una vez allí, solo hay que modificar en la URL `edit` por `timeline`.

---

Existe otra alternativa para poder acceder al historial de preguntas, y es instalar una extensión para el navegador, por ejemplo [Stack Overflow timeline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-timeline/omclkfdjappannhpjjngnnppfmidlbbh?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: En la captura es 100117.

Comment: @arteze no entiendo...

Comment: En la captura de pantalla el id del usuario dice 100117, pero en el punto 2 dice 100237.

Comment: @arteze ah,ya entiendo. De todas maneras,esta pregunta está obsoleta, ahora ya hay un acceso directo al timeline...